# Mariadb Kerberos Authentication in C++

Tags: c++, mariadb, kerberos

MariaDB instance is equipped with the Kerberos Authentication (`GSSAPI Authentication`) and using the command-line  & login by having a valid ticket.

For connecting to MariaDB in C++ we used the MariaDB Connector/C version `3.1.9` by installing the packages `MariaDB-common` and  `MariaDB-devel`. Currently the authentication is done by the username and password:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <string>
...
    try {
        // Format a MySQL object
        conn = mysql_init(NULL);

        // Establish a MariaDB connection
        if (!mysql_real_connect(
                conn,
                MY_HOSTNAME, MY_USERNAME,
                MY_PASSWORD, MY_DATABASE,
                MY_PORT_NO, MY_SOCKET, MY_OPT)) {
            cerr << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
            return false;
        }
```

But I need a way to use the Kerberos Authentication in our C++ application, however, I can not find any related document or example. So my question is, is there any way to connect the MariaDB using Kerberos Authentication in C++?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way on the client to force authentication via Kerberos/GSSAPI.

If GSSAPI is supported on the server and properly configured the server will negotiate with client that authentication will happen via GSSAPI. This happens during handshake (or when sending `COM_CHANGE_USER` command).

Beside GSSAPI configuration on the server, you also need to specify that the user should be identified via GSSAPI:

```
CREATE USER username@hostname IDENTIFIED VIA gssapi
```

More information can be found in the [MariaDB Knowledgebase](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-gssapi/).